# Get more than one Element JSoup Java Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to get a list of items to form a playlist, and I am only able to retrieve one of the items. Here is the code I have going to my recyclerview's bindView:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlaylistViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    try
    {
        String url = "https://www.c895.org/playlist";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Element playlist = document.select("#playlist").first();

        List<TrackInfo> tracks = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Element track : playlist.children())
        {
            long time = Long.parseLong(track.dataset().get("ts"));
            String title = track.select(".title").text();
            String artist = track.select(".artist").text();

            tracks.add(new TrackInfo(new Date(time * 1000), title, artist));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tracks.size() - 1; i++)
        {

            holder.titlesView.setText(tracks.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Ideally I'd like to get about 10-20 results. Is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: Can you please share some more of your code? I could not reproduce your problem yet. All the playlist values are in your track info list. Maybe only the last one in displayed.

Comment: Looks OK to me - I've modified your code a litte bit - I don't know what `TrackInfo` is and I've tried it under JVM not android, but my output is `Feel It-Max Styler
Wait Another Day-Mike Williams x Mesto
Breathe (ft. Jem Cooke)-CamelPhat X Cristoph
Hey Brother-Avicii` and so on - I have more than 200 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the html part that you need is in the following tag:

```
<div id="playlist">

</div>
```

So you can't use the following:

```
Element playlist = document.select("#playlist").first();
```

but you need to use `div#playlist` to get all the playlist item:

```
Element playlist = document.select("div#playlist");
```